# Cannot use vuex store getters from nuxt.js Middleware

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have getters setup within my Vuex store that I can access. I can also see the getters if I output the `context.store.getters` object in the console from my Middleware.

The problem is that if I try to actually use the getters in my Middleware (e.g., `context.store.getters.userType`) I receive errors that they are undefined. **Is there anyway to access the getters from middleware?**

Here is my middleware:

```
export default function (context) {
  console.log("context.store.getters", context.store.getters);
  console.log("context.store.getters.getUserType", 
  context.store.getters.getUserType)

  if (context.store.getters.getUserType == "adv") {
    return router.push('/adv')
  } else if (context.store.getters.getUserType == "applicant") {
    return router.push('/app')
  }
}
```

However, you can see that there is actually a defined and resultant "userType" getter in the store via the console:
[image]
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It just mean that at time when middleware executed value inside your getter is undefined.

Comment: Thanks @Aldarund. Is there a way to have the app wait for them to be defined before usage?

Comment: They are defined. I mean that value in  that specific getter is undefined, and your code that put some value in it run after middleware

Comment: @Aldarund, it actually is defined. Take a look at the console log image. You see the value in the output of `context.store.getters` but not in `context.store.getters.userType`. I see the value actually is defined. And it's also shown in my Vue Chrome Debugger, but it's not coming through when I explicitly call it. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: The thing is that when you log in console context.store.getters it log reference to the object. And the actual values will only be evaluated when you click. So its different moment from when you log.

Comment: Thanks. It's also looking like it has something to do with losing state when the page refreshes. Don't quite know what to do but thanks for the help.

Comment: It work as expected. State will be lost after page refresh. It is expected and how it should work.

Comment: Got it now. Things are working correctly; handled the refresh condition (and also used context.redirect instead of router.push) and things are working. Thanks again!